# C# Error of my line of code that it keep pop out Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table" after I run the code and inputted a value of 1

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const string V = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Simple;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const string ConnectionString = V;
            SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            conn1.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Id, First Name, Last Name, sum from Table where id=@id", conn1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", textBox1.Text);
            SqlDataReader reader1;
            reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if(reader1.Read())
            {
                textBox2.Text = reader1["First Name"].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = reader1["Last Name"].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = reader1["Sum"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no data found");
            }
            conn1.Close();

            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `Table` is a reserved word, best is to choose a different name for the table. Otherwise, enclose it in brackets: `[Table]`

Comment: `Sum` is also a reserved keyword and `First Name` and `Last Name` need also brackets around because of that empty space.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `SUM` isn't a T-SQL Reserved Keyword, just an [ODBC Reserved Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#odbc-reserved-keywords). Really though, it seems the OP should be changing the names of all their objects apart from `Id`.

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 1):

Is your column names have spaces in the database? Is it "First Name" or "FirstName" (same question for the last name)?

If it is `FirstName` and `LastName` then try this (I removed space from `First Name` and `LastName` and added brackets to the `sum` and `Table` as they are reserved words):

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Id, FirstName, LastName, [sum] from [Table] where id=@id", conn1);
```

If it is with space then try this:

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Id, [First Name], [Last Name], [sum] from [Table] where id=@id", conn1);
```

Note, it is not a good practice to use reserved names for your column names. I would recommend you to change the column names to non-reserved words.

Comment: The brackets should be used for column names as well. No need to remove the space

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar Yes, usually it is not a good practice to do spaced column names. As he didn't mention what are the column names, I assumed it is without spaces and this is his mistake. How do you know what he has in the database? (I will update my answer anyway)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Read my comment above ^^

Comment: When you assumed the OP's problem, which we have no evidence of the columns not actually having spaces in their names, why did assume their gender too (which we have no evidence of either)? `First Name` and `FirstName` are not the same. If the object name is really `First Name` this will just generate a different error.

Comment: why complicate the answer . just add `[First Name],[Last Name]`

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar I updated my answer, I gave the two options which are depends on the missing information...

Comment: Just put a bracket around every column, for the sake of completeness. I'm also not sure if the `SUM`-column could make a proplem somewhere. You could also mention that it were a good idea to change the column names to avoid these issues.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, I agree, updated my answer accordingly. About SUM it is working fine but I added a bracket anyway.